# Powershell SelectSingleNode not working with a namespace?

Tags: xml, powershell, selectsinglenode

So according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode.aspx) I should be able to do:

```
$ns = @{ns=$curNode.NamespaceURI}
$node = $curNode.SelectSingleNode('ns:tagName', $ns)
$node.value = '2'
```

to get the `tagName` node under the current `curNode`. But I get:

```
Cannot find an overload for "SelectSingleNode" and the argument count: "2".
```

So how do I go about getting to my child node to change its value?

If I just try

```
$node = $curNode.SelectSingleNode('tagName')
```

Then the `$node` is $null.

Comment: What is the type of $curNode?  Execute `$curNode.GetType().FullName`.

Comment: @KeithHill - System.Xml.XmlElement

Comment: SelectSingleNode() is a .NET method that expects that second argument to be an instance of an XmlNamespaceManager.  You can use your current syntax with Select-Xml e.g. `Select-Xml -Xml $curNode -XPath 'ns:tagName' -Namespace @{ns=$curNode.NamespaceUri}`.

Comment: If you want to use the .NET method then you need to create a XmlNamespaceManager for that second parameter e.g. `$nsmgr = new-object xml.xmlnamespacemanager $curNode.OwnerDocument.NameTable;$nsmgr.Add('ns', $curNode.NamespaceURI)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the value of an XmlElement node:

```
$curNode.'#text' = 2
```